# In-memory storage for flask application

Tags: python, flask

My flask application stores some data in a database.
I want this data to be discarded if my application has been down for some time.
The reason for this is that I want to be sure that I missed no REST call to my application.

The obvious and efficient solution is storing this data in memory but I am open to any solution (e.g. delete old records on application restart).

Comment: This answer has a lot of useful information as well, such as shared threads of a process (okay for non-prod), and Unix shared between processes (best for production): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720700/can-two-processes-access-in-memory-memory-sqlite-database-concurrently

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't need persistence in your application, why don't you use the SQLite backend ([easy in flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlite3/)) and store the database in memory (using the `:memory:` filename as data base), then on each shutdown your data will be cleaned.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I did not think about it.

Comment: and read https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html for backup even from mem, python version ~ https://github.com/husio/python-sqlite3-backup

Comment: In-memory databases won't work here because they cannot be accessed from different threads, and Flask creates a new thread for each request. You need to create the connection object in the request thread, and if you use in-memory DB then you got a blank DB. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381304

Answer (score 2):

You can use [persisted memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx). Python has a [facility](http://www.linux-support.com/cms/mmap-memory-mapped-files-in-python/) ([mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html)) to work with such files.

Comment: Thank you but I think I do *not* need persistence. I want to invalidate my data when my server goes down.