# flask manage db connection :memory:

Tags: sqlite, flask

I have a flask application that needs to store some information from requests. The information is quite short-lived and if the server is restarted I do not need it any more - so I do not really need persistence.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113903/in-memory-storage-for-flask-application) that an Sqlite database, which is held in memory can be used for that. What is the best way to manage the database connection? In the flask documentation connections to the database are created on demand, but my database [will be deleted if I close the connection](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

Comment: I think memcached is kind-of what you're looking for, but some more information about the data you're storing would be nice.

Comment: You can use Redis in that way or even MongoDB. Possibly, CouchDB might be able to set up in that way.

Comment: I want to implement something similar to port-knocking. A certain request can only succeed, if another request has been executed before. All I really need is a variable that can be read and written to consistently across all threads. What is the Flask way of doing this?

Comment: Although memcached etc are probably what you are looking for, if you want to use sqlite then a cheap trick is to use a database file on a partition mounted in RAM. If you want, you can delete the file on application exit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with using an in memory sqlite db is that your Sqlite in-memory databases cannot be accessed from multiple threads.

http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

To further the problem, you are likely going to have more than one process running your app, which makes using an in-memory global variable out of the question as well.

So unless you can be certain that your app will only ever require a single thread or a single process (which is unlikely) You're going to need to either:

1. Use the disk to store state, such as an on-disk sqlite db, or even just some file you parse.
2. Use a daemonized process that runs separately from your application to manage the state.

I'd personally go with option 2.

You can use memcached for this, running on a central server or even on your app server if you've only got one. This will allow you to store state (including python objects!) temporarily, in memory and you can even set timeout values for when the data should expire, which from the sound of things might be useful for your app.

Since you're using Flask, you've got some really good built-in support for using a memcached cache, check it out here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/caching/

As for getting memcached running on your server, it's really just an `apt-get` or `yum install` away. Let me know if you have questions or challenges and I'll be happy to update.