# Can two processes access in-memory (:memory:) sqlite database concurrently?

Tags: python, sqlite

Is it possible to access database in one process, created in another?
I tried:

**IDLE #1**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("create table test(testcolumn)")
c.execute("insert into test values('helloooo')")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

**IDLE #2**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("select * from test")
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    q = c.execute("select * from test")
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: test
```

Comment: Each process that connects to `:memory:` creates its own, unique, private database, invisible to all other processes.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, they cannot ever access the same in-memory database from different processes  Instead, a new connection to `:memory:` *always* creates a *new* database.

From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html):

> Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So, opening two database connections each with the filename ":memory:" will create two independent in-memory databases.

This is different from an on-disk database, where creating multiple connections with the same connection string means you are connecting to one database.

Within *one process* it is possible to share an in-memory database if you use the `file::memory:?cache=shared` URI:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('file::memory:?cache=shared', uri=True)
```

but this is still not accessible from other another process.

Comment: even "file::memory:?cache=shared" only allows separate database connections to share the same in-memory database. But, all database connections sharing the in-memory database need to be in the same process. https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: @corretge: the `file::memory:?cache=shared` url was only introduced a few months before I wrote this, I see. I've added a mention, but as you say this is not usable across multiple processes.

Comment: In Python 3.4+, you need to use the additional parameter `uri=True` to get the `connect()` method to open the string as a URI, instead of as a file. Otherwise it just creates a local file called `file::memory:?cache=shared`.

Comment: @Alexander: I’d say that’s an error on my part to have omitted it. Added now, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: you may also connect to multiple separate memory databases, if that is what you wish. in the following code, I believe the first example is effectively equivalent to the :memory: examples. ```.open file:?mode=memory&cache=shared ; 
.open file:memDb1?mode=memory&cache=shared ; 
.open file:memDb2?mode=memory&cache=shared ; 
.open file:memDb3?mode=memory&cache=shared ; 
```

Answer (score 28):

of course I agree with @Martijn because doc says so, but if you are focused on unix like systems, then you can make use of shared memory:

If you create file in `/dev/shm` folder, all files create there are mapped directly to RAM, so you can use to access the-same database from two-different processes.

```
#/bin/bash
rm -f /dev/shm/test.db
time bash -c $'
FILE=/dev/shm/test.db
sqlite3 $FILE "create table if not exists tab(id int);"
sqlite3 $FILE "insert into tab values (1),(2)"
for i in 1 2 3 4; do sqlite3 $FILE "INSERT INTO tab (id) select (a.id+b.id+c.id)*abs(random()%1e7) from tab a, tab b, tab c limit 5e5"; done; #inserts at most 2'000'000 records to db.
sqlite3 $FILE "select count(*) from tab;"'
```

it takes that much time:

```
FILE=/dev/shm/test.db
real    0m0.927s
user    0m0.834s
sys 0m0.092s
```

for at least 2 million records, doing the same on HDD takes (this is the same command but `FILE=/tmp/test.db`):

```
FILE=/tmp/test.db
real    0m2.309s
user    0m0.871s
sys 0m0.138s
```

so basically this allows you accessing the same databases from different processes (without loosing r/w speed):

Here is demo demonstrating this what I am talking about:

```
xterm -hold -e 'sqlite3 /dev/shm/testbin "create table tab(id int); insert into tab values (42),(1337);"' &
xterm -hold -e 'sqlite3 /dev/shm/testbin "insert into tab values (43),(1338); select * from tab;"' &
;
```

Comment: Don't use `/dev/shm` itself, create another instance of `tmpfs`, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/42884337/846250