# How and when to use /dev/shm for efficiency?

Tags: linux, performance, io, filesystems, shared-memory

How is `/dev/shm` more efficient than writing the file on the regular file system? As far as I know, `/dev/shm` is also a space on the HDD so the read/write speeds are the same.

My problem is, I have a 96GB file and only 64GB RAM (+ 64GB swap). Then, multiple threads from the same process need to read small random chunks of the file (about 1.5MB).

Is `/dev/shm` a good use case for this?
Will it be faster than opening the file in read-only mode from `/home` and then passing over to the threads to do the reading the required random chunks?

Comment: `/dev/shm` is not on the hard disk. It's a virtual filesystem implemented in memory, that's why it's faster.

Comment: @Barmar right, just realised that... Then makes sense to use it, especially since it can be shared from multiple processes so it won't take 96GB per process that wants to use it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't use `/dev/shm`. It exists so that the POSIX C library can provide shared memory support via the POSIX API. Not so you can poke at stuff in there.

If you want an in-memory filesystem of your very own, you can mount one wherever you want it.

`mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/tmp`, for example.

A Linux `tmpfs` is a temporary filesystem that only exists in RAM. It is implemented by having a file cache without any disk storage behind it. It will write its contents into the swap file under memory pressure. If you didn't want the swapfile you can use a `ramfs`.

I don't know where you got the idea of using `/dev/shm` for efficiency in reading files, because that isn't what it does at all.

Maybe you were thinking of using memory mapping, via the `mmap` system call?

Read this answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1030777/4642 it covers a lot of tmpfs information.

Comment: I got the idea from here https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/storage.md#torchtypestoragefilename--shared--size--sharedmem

So I was thinking whether is better to have the storage file in the shared memory or not.

Comment: So if I map the 96GB file there it will take up all the RAM + half of the swap file, right? The problem with that is that it will take a lot of time, the RAM data transfer is about 130MB per second so it will take 1.5 min to load all the data.

Comment: @ilija139 It's virtual memory, it's only swapped in when needed.

Comment: @ilija139: You didn't put a tag for your language or framework. If you can use memory mapping (mmap) then that is the best way for your shared, random access from multiple programs problem. With memory mapping the operating system will treat the file as a virtual memory swap file, loading and unloading pieces of it on demand.

Comment: If you are using that Torch thing, I believe you just want to use the `shared` flag it provides on Storage. It says right in the description that it maps the file into memory, and shared makes it available for many programs at once.

Comment: @ZanLynx yes, thanks. It wasn't moving the memory to RAM that's why I though it's reading it from the disk. But, I realized that it moves to shared memory space as it loads chunks of data, not all at once, and, it doesn't show up in htop, although it shows in free under shared memory.

Comment: This answer is largely incorrect.  The /dev/shm space on Linux IS an exposed tmpfs block device.  It is *precisely* for sticking things in there. It has a max allocation of 1/2 available ram.  e.g. 32GB is available if ram is 64GB is installed.  /dev/shm may be a good use case depending on how random your reads are for the large file.  If most are to the front 1/3 of the 96gb, then go ahead and copy that fraction directly to /dev/shm .  Unused memory is wasted time.  /dev/shm doesn't improve multiple reads to the same file location though, as that data will already be cached.

Comment: @Beracah you are wrong about /dev/shm, because it is an implementation detail of POSIX shared memory support. If you want a tmpfs, *mount your own*

Comment: @Zan ; mistaken, please read the docs.  Don't confuse POSIX shared memory used for IPC with the provided /dev/shm mount.

Comment: @Beracah You don't know the naming convention for the files created by the library. Messing around in /dev/shm is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Zan don't presume to tell a user what he should or should not do with his own shm , based on speculative collisions.  It lowers the utility of the computer and the service provided.  Beyond that, provided the author doesn't write everything as root, standard kernel permissions will ensure no collisions occur.  It isn't even possible to pollute the running kernel in that manner anyway.

Comment: @Beracah I see you *completely missed* what I said about mounting your own tmpfs filesystem whereever you want it that *isn't* /dev/shm.

Comment: I saw that comment, and I didn't address it because your very rationale for mounting elsewhere was misguided and incorrect right from the start.  There is nothing wrong with using the kernel provided "shared memory", which also has a filesystem, and has been specifically provided by the kernel for user level access.  If you want, you can share it directly on samba, and choose the permissions to give areas in that space.

Comment: @ZanLynx : `mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt/tmp` can only be done by root, so `/dev/shm` is a good solution to boost I/O performance for users. See https://superuser.com/questions/45342/when-should-i-use-dev-shm-and-when-should-i-use-tmp

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt says "glibc 2.2 and above expects tmpfs to be mounted at /dev/shm for
   POSIX shared memory". It never says "don't use /dev/shm".