# In memory SQLite3 shared database python

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, sqlite

I am trying to make the best out of an aws server and had the idea to use an in memory database across multiple threads(using SQLite 3 in python) I found this command online:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('file::memory:?cache=shared')
```

but then I get this vague error:

```
    sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Is it even possible to do this anymore?

Comment: What do you mean by "anymore"?

Comment: I saw somewhere that shared memory databases are not supported anymore

Comment: Try the code in my answer. If it works, the problem is just in your code. You're probably releasing your DB somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** still possible. I just verified against `Python 3.6.0` and `Python 2.7.13` on `MacOS`.

`sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared")` is indeed the correct way to connect to DB.

```
import sqlite3
p = sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared")
p.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (bar, baz)')
p.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('apple', 'orange')")
p.commit()
```

and in another python shell

```
import sqlite3
q = sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared")
list(q.execute('SELECT * FROM foo'))
```

my output is `[(u'apple', u'orange')]`

To you answer your question "Is it even possible to do this anymore?", the answer is **yes**. So the problem lies in your system, as you confirmed it works on aws (in the comments below).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it oout

Comment: so I tried this and it works when I try to read the database from the same shell I created it in but when I open a new shell it says "table not found foo"

Comment: @EmanuelAmit how about another shell when this shell is still running?

Comment: I just tried it in pycharm too through two seperate programs and it did not work

Comment: @EmanuelAmit oh.. I tried it on my digital ocean server running Ubuntu and   it worked as expected. This probably needs more indepth examination. What version of python and OS are you running on aws and on your local laptop?

Comment: if you are using ubuntu, try creating a file inside `/dev/shm/` and using that as file db.
apparently, files in `/dev/shm` directly mapped to RAM. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720700/can-two-processes-access-in-memory-memory-sqlite-database-concurrently

Comment: So I just tried it again and it worked on aws. Before I was just running it on my machine (macOS). why could it be that it works on aws but not on my local machine? Thank You

Comment: Glad that it worked. I'm running the same code in macOS and it worked here. I tried it in HyperTerm as well as default macOS terminal. I don't really know why this could have happened.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.4+ and SQLite 3.7.13+, you can use this approach:

```
sqlite3.connect("file:memory?cache=shared&mode=memory", uri=True)
```