# SQLite3 with flask in-memory mode

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, connexion

I am using `sqlite3` in a flask app (actually connexion).
I would like to stay in-memory but keep the db between the requests to the server.
So it should be destroyed after server is killed

- When I use sqlite3.connect(':memory:') the db is destroyed after each response
- So I followed this approach [In memory SQLite3 shared database python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090121/in-memory-sqlite3-shared-database-python) and run `sqlite3.connect('file::memory:?cache=shared&mode=memory', uri=True)`. But then, a file called `file::memory:?cache=shared&mode=memory` appears in the app root and does not disappear when I kill the server. When I start the server again, the db-init routine which creates the tables fails, because the tables are already created.

I tried this out on linux and Mac. Both have same behaviour. It seems like the db is saved to file instead of being mapped to memory.
My python version is 3.9 and `sqlite3.sqlite_version_info` is (3, 37, 0)

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that sqlite is treating this `'file::memory:?cache=shared&mode=memory'` as a file name. Therefore on execution, creates a database file with that "name", in it's root directory.

Now to the issue I would try connecting via:

```
 sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
```

and to keep it alive you could try, opening a connection before starting to serve the app, store the connection object somewhere so it doesn't get garbage collected, and proceed as usual opening and closing other connections to it (on per-request basis).

SOS: Keep in mind I have only tested it in a single thread script to check if a new `sqlite3.connect(':memory:')` connects to the same database that we have already loaded (it does).
I do not know how well it would play with flask's threads, or sqlite it self.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's my approach, more info below:

```
class db_test:
    # DOES NOT INCLUDE LOADING THE FILE TO MEMORY AND VICE VERSA (out of the scope of the question)
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", check_same_thread=False)

    def execute_insert(self, query: str, data: tuple):
        cur = self.db.cursor()
        with self.db:
            cur.execute(query, data)
        cur.close()
```

The above class is instantiated once in the beginning of my flask app, right after imports like so:

```
from classes import db_test
db = db_test()
```

This avoids garbage collection.

To use, simply call where is need like so:

```
@app.route("/db_test")
def db_test():
    db.execute_insert("INSERT INTO table (entry) VALUES (?)", ('hello', ))
    return render_template("db_test.html")
```

**Notes:**

You might have noticed the 2nd argument in `self.db = sq.connect(":memory:", check_same_thread=False)`. This makes it possible to use connections and cursors created in different threads (as flask does), but at the risk of collisions and corrupting data/entries.

From my understanding (regarding my setup flask->waitress->nginx), unless explicitely set to some multithreaded/multiprocessing mode, flask will process each request start-to-finish and then proceed to the next. Thus rendering above danger, irrelevant.

I set up a rudimentary test to see if my theory holds up. I would insert an incremental number every time a page is requested. I then SPAMMED refresh on pc, laptop & mobile. The resulting 164 entries were checked for integrity manually and passed.

Finally: Keep in mind that I might be missing something, that my methodology is not of a stress-test and the differences between our setups.

Hope this helps!

PS: The first approach I suggested could not be replicated inside flask. I suspect that is due to flasks thread activity.