# Deleting a database file in :memory:

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-unittest

#### Background and Question

We are using `:memory:` to store our database when we are testing and would like to remove this before each test case run so that we will start from the beginning with an empty database for each test case. (If we were storing the database on the disk we would simply remove the file)

#### Our Setup

- We are using Python's `unittest` module
- (Python version: 3.6)
- This is what our database creation looks like: `db_connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")`

---

How can we delete our database from memory?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that calling `self.db_connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")` in `setUp` will make sure you get a "new" db for every test. Then use `self.db_connection` in every test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the connection method `close()`. It will close your connection to the database. If the database is in memory, you should not be able to reconnect to it.

You can test this simply:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE test (col1 text, col2 text)')
c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('good', 'day')")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

We can then check if we can access the database after.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
print(c.fetchall())
```

> c.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
>
> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: test

This shows us that when you close the database in memory, it is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you, this works for me! [Here is our database close function](https://github.com/mindfulness-at-the-computer/mindfulness-at-the-computer/blob/master/mc/db.py#L207) at the moment after updating with information from your answer. (This function is called from the `tearDown` function). The reason that we never needed to explicitly close our database before

Comment: The first part is correct, the in-memory db can be closed with `.close()`. But your way of proofing this is wrong. Each time `sqlite3.connect(':memory:')` is called, a completely new database is created in memory. So your second `.connect(':memory:')` won't access the same memory as the first `.connect(':memory:')`, regardless of weather you write `.close()` or leave it away. See: [SQL in-memory docs](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720700/can-two-processes-access-in-memory-memory-sqlite-database-concurrently).